# Passing parent entity Id into child form

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

Good day,
I got entity ScheduledCommand into relation OneToMany to ScheduledCommandLimitRange

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass (repositoryClass="Synolia\SyliusSchedulerCommandPlugin\Repository\ScheduledCommandRepository")
 * @ORM\Table("scheduled_command")
 */
class ScheduledCommand implements ScheduledCommandInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int|null
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $command = '';

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $priority = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ScheduledCommandLimitRange", mappedBy="scheduledCommand", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $commandLimitRanges;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): ScheduledCommandInterface
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCommand(): string
    {
        return $this->command;
    }

    public function setCommand(string $command): ScheduledCommandInterface
    {
        $this->command = $command;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPriority(): int
    {
        return $this->priority;
    }

    public function setPriority(int $priority): ScheduledCommandInterface
    {
        $this->priority = $priority;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCommandLimitRanges(): ?Collection
    {
        return $this->commandLimitRanges;
    }

    public function setCommandLimitRanges(Collection $commandLimitRange): ?Collection
    {
        $this->commandLimitRanges = $commandLimitRange;
        return $this->commandLimitRanges;
    }
}
```

This is my ManyToOne class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Synolia\SyliusSchedulerCommandPlugin\Repository\ScheduledCommandLimitRangeRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="scheduled_command_limit_range")
 */
class ScheduledCommandLimitRange implements ScheduledCommandLimitRangeInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $timeFrom;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $timeTo;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ScheduledCommand", inversedBy="commandLimitRanges")
     */
    private $scheduledCommand;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTimeFrom(): ?\DateTime
    {
        return $this->timeFrom;
    }

    public function setTimeFrom(?\DateTime $timeFrom): ScheduledCommandLimitRangeInterface
    {
        $this->timeFrom = $timeFrom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTimeTo(): ?\DateTime
    {
        return $this->timeTo;
    }

    public function setTimeTo(?\DateTime $timeTo): ScheduledCommandLimitRangeInterface
    {
        $this->timeTo = $timeTo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getScheduledCommand(): ?ScheduledCommand
    {
        return $this->scheduledCommand;
    }
    public function setScheduledCommand(ScheduledCommand $scheduledCommand): ?ScheduledCommand
    {
        $this->scheduledCommand = $scheduledCommand;

        return $this;
    }
```

I got ScheduledCommandType that is has CollectionType in one field, that has entry_type of CommandLimitType.

```
final class ScheduledCommandType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('command', CommandChoiceType::class)
            ->add('arguments')
            ->add('cronExpression')
            ->add('commandLimitRanges', CollectionType::class, [
                'label' => 'sylius.ui.scheduled_command_limit',
                'entry_type' => CommandLimitType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'inherit_data' => true,
                'entry_options'  => array(
                        'scheduledCommand' => 'id'),
                ])
            ->add('logFile')
            ->add('priority')
            ->add('executeImmediately')
            ->add('enabled')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ScheduledCommand::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is my entry Type:

```
class CommandLimitType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('timeTo', DateTimeType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text',

            ])
            ->add('timeFrom', DateTimeType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text'
            ])
            ->add('scheduledCommand', HiddenType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired(['scheduledCommand']);
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ScheduledCommandLimitRange::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I had a problem, that when I want to submit this form value CommandLimitRange parentId was null, so i tried to pass into child form parent Id as hidden field. But still got after submit there is stil error:

```
Cannot read index "0" from object of type "Synolia\SyliusSchedulerCommandPlugin\Entity\ScheduledCommand" because it doesn't implement \ArrayAccess.
```

What is correct way to pass parent entity Id into entry so that after submit correct parentId is linked to row in db?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution. Okay, so here is few problems, that I did not clearly understand before.
First and foremost - I had only basic setter, instead add / remove method.

```
public function addCommandLimitRange(ScheduledCommandLimitRange $commandLimitRange): self
    {
        if (!$this->commandLimitRanges->contains($commandLimitRange)) {
            $this->commandLimitRanges[] = $commandLimitRange;
            $commandLimitRange->setScheduledCommand($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
    public function removeCommandLimitRange(ScheduledCommandLimitRange $commandLimitRange): self
    {
        if ($this->commandLimitRanges->removeElement($commandLimitRange)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($commandLimitRange->getScheduledCommand() === $this) {
                $commandLimitRange->setScheduledCommand(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Next I needed to make my property an ArrayCollection object in constructor:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->commandLimitRanges = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

And last to get proper delete instead running update with null on parentId I needed to ad orphan_removal option into annotation.

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ScheduledCommandLimitRange", mappedBy="scheduledCommand", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $commandLimitRanges;
```